# Create 2D RPG, searching a canvas library

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a small RPG.
You can see my actual work [here](http://www.whiteplay.fr/rpg/) (IE don't support) to understand what i want.
I'm not using any Library.
And because of it, the game can lag on small computers (like mine).
Do you know a js Library (with canvas) i can use to make this project real ?
This should allow me to :
- Create multiple layers (the character has to go behind some objects).
- Allow me slide object (i don't whant my character to make 16 small tp to move, i need a slide method).
- And i need it to have MIT license.

PS : I tried : pixi.js and melon.js and i'm not shure they are what i need.

Thanks for all of your answers, and have a good day :D

Comment: I'll go out with my dog, I'll come back. If you want to answer me directly my email is : duvalantoine7614@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

> I'll go out with my dog, I'll come back.

**LOL!** We have a Miniature Pinscher named "Scrappy" -- he's all of 5 pounds soaking wet, but he has the heart of a Lion! I'll post a quick answer, then go out with Scrappy & I'll come back. :-)

**1. Layering**

Html Canvas does not have layers, but you can give your game elements a z-index property to indicate the order in which they should be drawn to the canvas -- the result is basic layering.

*(Without reviewing your code base)* You probably have each of your game pieces stored in their own javascript object and probably have JS objects stored inside an array. That JS object probably contains the x,y coordinate where that game piece is to be drawn.

```
var player1={
    x:50,
    y:25
}

var gameObjects=[player1];
```

To add z-indexing (layering), all you have to do is add a `z` property to each game piece object:

```
var player1={
    x:50,
    y:25,
    z:100,
}
```

Use that `z` property just like HTML/CSS does to layer the content of a web page.

If you need player2 to be in back of player1 you just make player2's `z` property lower than player1's `z` property.

```
// player2 will be "layered" behind player1 because their z is lower
var player2={
    x:200,
    y:250,
    z:90,
}
```

Then before redrawing the canvas for your next game frame, you just sort the gameObjects array on the z property. The result is that all your game objects have your desired layering (z-indexing). Sorting an array in javascript is very fast.

Here's an example of the Moon and (optionally) Satellites orbiting the Earth. The `z` property of the Moon & Satellites are used to layer them appropriately in-front-of or behind the Earth:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

$timer=$('#timer');

var satellite=document.createElement("canvas");
var actx=satellite.getContext("2d");
satellite.width=5;
satellite.height=5;
actx.beginPath();
actx.arc(3,3,2,0,Math.PI*2);
actx.closePath();
actx.fillStyle='gray';
actx.fill();

var nextTime=0;
var delay=1000/60*1;
var PI=Math.PI
var PI2=PI*2;

var images=[];
var earth=new Image();
earth.onload=start;
earth.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/earth.png';
var moon=new Image();
moon.onload=start;
moon.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/moon.png';
var imgCount=2;
function start(){
  if(--imgCount>0){return;}   
  images.push(makeImage(earth,cw/2,ch/2,0,1.00,0,0,function(){return(200);}));
  images.push(makeImage(moon,cw/2,ch/2,cw/2-moon.width/2-10,.20,Math.PI/120,0,function(){return((this.angle>PI)?100:300);}));
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  $('#satellites').click(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
      images.push(makeImage(
        satellite,cw/2,ch/2,earth.width/2+Math.random()*25,Math.random()*.75,Math.PI/120*Math.random()*3,0,function(){return((this.angle>PI)?190:210);}
      ));
    }
  });

}

function update(){
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    var img=images[i];
    img.angle=(img.angle+img.deltaAngle+PI2)%PI2;
    img.z=img.calcZ();;
  }
  images.sort(function(a,b){return a.z - b.z});
}


function animate(time){
  if(time<nextTime){requestAnimationFrame(animate); return;}
  nextTime=time+delay;
  var t1=performance.now();
  draw();
  update();
  $timer.text(images.length+' images in '+parseFloat(performance.now()-t1).toFixed(1)+' ms');
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    var img=images[i];
    var x=img.cx+img.radius*Math.cos(img.angle);
    var y=img.cy+img.radius*Math.sin(img.angle)*img.scaleY;
    ctx.drawImage(img.image,x-img.image.width/2,y-img.image.height/2);
  }
}


function makeImage(img,cx,cy,radius,orbitFlattenY,deltaA,angle,calcZ){
  return{
    cx:cx,
    cy:cy,
    z:0,
    calcZ:calcZ,
    radius:radius,
    scaleY:orbitFlattenY,
    angle:angle,
    deltaAngle:deltaA,
    image:img
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='satellites'>Add 10 satellites</button>
<span id='timer'>Update+Draw time=#ms</span>
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
```

**2. Sliding your game pieces**

Html Canvas does not allow "sliding" because it cannot move anything drawn on itself. The Canvas process is always to erase the canvas and redraw the pieces in their new positions.

Having said that, you can get a smoother "slide" rather than a "jump" by changing the [x,y] of your pieces in smaller increments:

```
// instead of x+=2
x+=0.50;
```

Since the incremental movement is smaller (0.50 instead of 2.00), you might need to move that piece 4X (2/0.50) times more often.

**3. Licensing**

I think Stackoverflow answers automatically have "Creating Commons" licensing, so feel free to use my answer in your RPG--I don't even need attribution :-)

Comment: First thanks for you time and your help, but i already tried to move my game pièces by small parts, but with this, the game si lagging when i'm moving :/ Have you any time to contact me ? Thanks agani :D